# Count blocks allocated with malloc() from external program

Tags: c, linux, malloc

I want to write a "simple" memory leak checker.

In order to do that I need to count a number of the `malloc()`ed memory blocks in a program, 
but the problem that I do not want to modify it's source.

In other words, I want to implement the following interface:

```
memory_check <executable name>
```

Where I do not have an access to the executable's source.

Firstly I supposed to try intercept a system call. But I read "[So malloc doesn't invoke any syscall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326474/so-malloc-doesnt-invoke-any-syscall)" and it doesn't seem to be an idea, also because of it will extremely slow all system (as I can suppose).

Are there any other options to intercept the `malloc()` calls?

Comment: The program you're trying to write already exists. It's called [valgrind](http://valgrind.org), and it does a lot more than just checking for leaks.

Comment: @duskwuff, I know about it, but didn't you ever tried to write something existing in order to improve your skills?

Comment: You may want to take a look at how valgrind works, then. It's not intercepting calls, exactly -- it's doing something much trickier and fancier. Study it and you will learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to change your interface to `LD_PRELOAD=mymalloc.so <executable>` you can do it like so:

- Make a shared library that

  - Gets a handle to `malloc` using `dlsym`
  - Exposes an external `void *malloc(size_t size)`
  - Calls the real `malloc` via the handle obtained above, and also stores your debug info

Then:

- Call the program `LD_PRELOAD=mymalloc.so ./program`
- The program automatically calls your "hijacked" version of `malloc`

---

#### EDIT

If you don't want to change your interface but want to use this trick you can make a wrapper program that `fork(2)`s, sets up `LD_PRELOAD` and then execs your real program using its name.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15213-s03/src/interposition/mymalloc.c

Comment: (+1) The wrapper program could be a simple shell script.

Answer (score 0):

If the executable is dynamically linked, then you can write your own malloc, and build it into a .so, in your own malloc, you can simply increament a counter:

```
#ifdef malloc
#undef malloc
#endif

static int count;
void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    count++;
    return _malloc(size);
}
```

then use LD_PRELOAD to preload your own malloc so.