# Memory info of process in bytes / words / whatever

Tags: bash, process

I want to know what size is the memory allocated to a specific process, and to do so I've used this rudimentary `bash` script:

```
PID=$(pgrep $1 | tail -1)
grep Vm /proc/$PID/status
```

Unfortunately, the `status` document only displays `Vm` information in kB, and I need to be able to see in greater detail. Matter of fact, I'd like to be able to harness memory information of a process at *any* possible resolution. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: `bash` runs on several OSs, and this is a very OS-specific question. Which are you talking about? In most cases, VM is allocated in pages with sizes that are even numbers of kilobytes. So better resolution isn't useful.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I am operating on Linux 64-bit (precisely with Mint 18.2). I should also specify that this is for pedagogical purposes

Comment: You can't allocate less than a page from the OS; your language's libraries might break what the OS gives it down into smaller pieces, but there's no point to trying to measure in bytes: The operating system doesn't have the data.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, all-caps names are in a namespace for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; you're at less risk for conflicts with a future/alternative shell's builtin variable if you name your variable `pid` rather than `PID`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable.

Comment: Getting back to your question: [So malloc doesn't invoke any syscall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326474/so-malloc-doesnt-invoke-any-syscall)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful, this is the information from `vmstat` man page:

```
NOTES
[...]
       All  linux  blocks  are  currently  1024  bytes. Old kernels may report
       blocks as 512 bytes, 2048 bytes, or 4096 bytes.

       Since procps 3.1.9, vmstat lets you choose units (k, K, m,  M)  default 
       is K (1024 bytes) in the default mode
```

In my system (64 bit RedHat) one page has 4096 bytes:

```
$ getconf PAGE_SIZE
4096
```